# WebClient Callback Async-Result?

Tags: c#, webclient

I would like to write a class which has handles my WebClient-Tasks and returns its results.
The problem is, that async downloads won't let a simple `return` handle:

```
public void checkAvailability()
{
     WebClient wc = new WebClient();
     wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
     wc.UploadStringCompleted += wc_UploadStringCompleted;
     wc.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("http://random.php"), "?lookup=10");

     //return parsed content from wc_UploadStringCompleted
}

private void wc_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     // do something
}
```

How can I put it all together to make it work?

Comment: What .NET version are you using? With the latest one you could make use of `async/await`, if not - you can only use callbacks.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2012. Could you please write that piece of code that you mean?

Answer (score 3):

OK, with Visual Studio 2012 and .NET 4.5 it's easier to use the `UploadStringTaskAsync()` method from the `System.Net.WebClient` class:

```
public async Task<string> CheckAvailability()
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    var result = await webClient.UploadStringTaskAsync(new Uri("http://random.php"), "?lookup=10");
    return result;
}
```

Any exception thrown by the method will interrupt your application flow like a regular, non-asynchronous method. Do note though that you have to `await` for this method wherever you call it to get the result, too, so:

```
var availability = await CheckAvailability();
```

in some other `async` marked method.

If you don't want to use this, you have to use callbacks:

```
public void CheckAvailability(Action<Exception, string> callback)
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    webClient.UploadStringCompleted += (s,e) => { 
                                                    if(e.Error != null)
                                                        callback(e.Error, string.Empty);
                                                    else
                                                        callback(null, e.Result);
                                                };
    wc.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("http://random.php"), "?lookup=10");
}
```

Now you have to pass the function returning `void` and taking two parameters of type `Exception` and `string` that will execute when the upload is finished, but you have to handle exceptions manually.

Comment: `UploadStringTaskAsync` is not available on the Windows Phone 8 SDK?

Comment: I just had to install a NuGet-Package. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

usse UploadStringTaskAsync indeed a better choice!

```
string data = "lookup=10";
string json = await WebClient.UploadStringTaskAsync(Uri, data);
```

the post data don't need "?"